# Accessing SalesForce with Cypress.IO

Tags: cypress, salesforce-lightning

I am attempting to access SalesForce through Cypress but as soon as I sign in the test stops and SalesForce takes over the entire browser.I am able to visit my SalesForce Sandbox page but I cannot get a test to progress beyond there.
[Where the test ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD7zW.png)

Here is my code to access SalesForce:

```
///<reference types="Cypress"/>

describe("Visit SalesForce with Request", function()
{

  it("Visits SalesForce", function()
  {
    const url = "https://test.lightning.force.com";
    const username = "user@compnamy.com.ecommerce";
    const password = "password";

    cy.request(`${url}/?un=${username}&pw=${password}`)
    .then(() =>
    {
        cy.visit(url);

        // Sign in to SalesForce 
        cy.get('#wrap').find('input').eq(2).click();

        // Does not execute beyond this point
        cy.reload();
        cy.log("Hello, world!");
    });

  });
});
```

Any advice on how to get Cypress tests to with the SalesForce would be greatly appreciated.